# How to make interface swi prolog program with html

Tags: html, prolog, swi-prolog

i had swi program about suggestion a starting eleven of arsenal fc, to make user can use it easily i want to make an interfaces to my program with using html .

how to make swi prolog insert to html?

Comment: On behalf of [@user27815](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3443189/user27815)  : Tutorial for web applications is here: http://www.pathwayslms.com/swipltuts/html/